# Android view shadow visible on lancher screen on home pressed

Tags: android

While dragging and holding android view, press home button. 
Shadow of dragging view is visible on android launcher(home) screen which should not, until finger is removed from shadow.

I could listen the home button pressed event in my activity, but I don't know how to dismiss the view shadow on home button pressed.